# HTML-CSS - Unable to pull image down to bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I'd like to pull down to the bottom of a div. In otherwords I want to convert this:
[image: bad align]

To this:

[image: good align]

I have tried to do this with CSS using something like creating a class for the img and doing:

```
.align-bottom img {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

That doesn't seem to do anything at all. If I set the position to be absolute then it puts the img at the bottom of the whole page and not just the div. How can this be done?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uezwpw40/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bottom` only works with `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` position elements so that will do nothing in this case. One way to do this with out using those would be to remove the `float:left` and use `display: inline-block` instead. `inline-block` elements align to the baseline by default (you would have to change the `width` of `.col-xs-11` because of the spacing `inline-block` causes):

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-11{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.col-xs-11{
  width: 90%;    
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uezwpw40/6/)

**

### OR

**

If you would prefer to use `bottom` you can set the parent `.row` to `position: relative`, reset `.col-xs-1` to `position: static` and add `position: absolute` to your image:

```
.row{
  position: relative;
}

.col-xs-1{
  position: static;
}

.align-bottom img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

[ALT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uezwpw40/7/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uezwpw40/3/)

Use the `position: absolute;` to position it with `bottom: 0;` and make sure the container has a position setting other than `static` (which is default if not specified).

**CSS:**

```
.titlebox {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#ddd;
    height: 100%;
}
.titlebox img {
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML (changed part):**

```
<div class="titlebox">  
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/u/O/S/m/D/pyramid.svg" width="30px">
```

You don't need it in its own `<div>` just put it wherever.  It'll be absolute so other elements won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use positioning in order to use bottom like that. How about a CSS solution similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gngur22r/

```
.titlebox {
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.bottom-background-arrow {
    background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Y/u/O/S/m/D/pyramid.svg");
    background-position: 20px bottom;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

This also allows you to retain the `.row > .col-*` formatted desired for bootstrap. Just change the background size and position as desired for better positioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the position to relative, you can position the image wherever you like:

```
.titlebox {
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.align-bottom img {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
```

I gave your .titlebox class a height so I can better guess where to position the image based on the dimensions of its encompassing div.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uezwpw40/5/